# Select only one of a type from a list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a class like this

```
class Person {
 private Id;
 private parentId;
 private Name;
}
```

I have a list of person which looks something like this :

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person{Id =1, Name = "Andy", parentId = 0});
persons.Add(new Person{Id =2, Name = "Sandy", parentId = 0});
persons.Add(new Person{Id =3, Name = "Carter", parentId = 9});
persons.Add(new Person{Id =4, Name = "Mark", parentId = 9});
persons.Add(new Person{Id =5, Name = "Martin", parentId = 99});
persons.Add(new Person{Id =6, Name = "Matt", parentId = 99});
```

What I want is :

```
persons.Add(new Person{Id =1, Name = "Andy", parentId = 0});
persons.Add(new Person{Id =2, Name = "Sandy", parentId = 0});
persons.Add(new Person{Id =3, Name = "Carter", parentId = 9});
persons.Add(new Person{Id =6, Name = "Matt", parentId = 99});
```

I want to keep all person with parentId 0 but choose only one from multiple grouped objects.

Thanks

Comment: What is the criteria for choosing "only one from multiple grouped objects"? Carter and Matt don't look like they were chosen alphabetically or by Id...?

Comment: @alice7 Dave's question is quite important to the solution. How do you want to choose the chosen sibling?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Its only important if it is relevant. The current requirement is to choose one and without specification (and indeed from observation) it doesn't seem to matter which so that is the problem we should solve.

Comment: @Chris In that case all we can go on is the provided output (which no answers would achieve assuming the order of input). I believe it is relevant and can potentially make the provided answers incorrect. If it is not relevant, that should also be clarified.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Don't get me wrong, I'm not going to complain if clarification is made. Its more that you seem to think that it is definitely important which it might not be.

Comment: @Chris I think it is personally, and the lack of OP response only strengthens the lessening quality this question is providing. At the end of the day if you correlate what the question wants with what the answers provide, they don't line up.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I think what the question says and what my answer gives line up to my reading of both. I suspect this may be a matter of opinion or semantics though so is probably best for us to agree to disagree.

Comment: @Chris Yes if you assume *any* person in the group is required. Given no criteria for selection, the next best is to use the example output (which no answer matches given the provided input). Unless we also assume that is also not relevant? Wish there was a way to close for lack of OP input.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I see your point actually. Updated my answer to demonstrate how to use an order clause to change what is selected. :) Also I think you've got to give it 24 hours at least before complaining there is lack of OP input. They might have posted it just before leaving work or something and are not going to look again til tomorrow. Annoying but not everybody is as addicted to this place. :)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth The OP gave the requirement that one of the siblings be selected without further specifying which one matters.  That means that there isn't just one right solution, there are a number of "correct" answers depending on which combination of children you decide to choose.  That someone else's output isn't an exact match for the OP's example doesn't make it wrong; the OP provided one of several correct answers, and the other posters provided a different, but equally correct, solution to this problem.

Comment: @Servy I'd always aim for the desired output if specified. The more assumptions that are made the less potential value the answer has. This is why I think it's important to get clarification.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth That's perfectly fine if you want to add that additional constraint to your own answers, or ask the OP to be more explicit about the fact that he doesn't care how the children are selected, but stating that the existing answers are incorrect is not proper; given the requirements listed they are correct.

Comment: @Servy they are not correct if you take the desired output as part of the requirements. I prefer to at least do that instead of supplying an answer and correcting the question to fit it.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth If you take something that's not a requirement and treat it as a requirement then sure, you can come up with something different.  But it's not a requirement, it's an example.  The two aren't the same thing.  As I said, if you want to hold yourself to that higher standard, feel free, but expecting others to invent a requirement that's not given is something I disagree with.

Comment: @chris Fair shout on the input, its just a little irritating sometimes seeing answers appear before stuff is clarified. None of the answerers queried the logic.

Comment: @servy it isn't making up a requirement, its seeking clarification instead of making the assumption the provided details are wrong, which all answers initially did. There is no need to put words in my mouth stating I'm inventing what isn't there, examples are part of the context of requirements and must be considered. Stating answers are incorrect is perfectly proper, this is how SO works.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth It's not assuming that the example is wrong, it's assuming that there are multiple valid answers, rather than just one.  That's a perfectly reasonable requirement to have.  Neither the example, nor any of the answers are wrong; the requirement is that any child, based on any criteria, can be chosen.  The OP used some different set of criteria for his example from the answerers; that doesn't make either wrong, merely different.  Assuming that an example is the only valid answer, rather than one of several possible which his wording states, *is* inventing a requirement.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I commented "This could be tweaked if you wanted to further refine the choice of which one to choose." which I personally feels covered the "and in case you forgot to specify further refinements". In hindsight I agree that matching the example is what I should have done but I didn't actually notice that it was not choosing the first and just went by the wording.

Comment: @servy His wording states he wants the following output... To me that is actually quite explicit. He then muddies it a little by stating is chosen but not how. All i did was raise the question about how, also pointing out it is important because it can make a misinterpetted "correct" answer incorrect. I then spend numerous comments defending my justification of its importance. I am now on a train typing this on a phone, which isn't fun, so I'm bowing out here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick (seems to from testing).

```
var rootItems = persons.Where(x=>x.parentId==0);
var childItems = persons.Where(x=>x.parentId!=0).GroupBy(x=>x.parentId).Select(x=>x.First());
var requiredItems = rootItems.Concat(childItems);
```

It basically does it in two parts, the first simply gets all the root items. The second groups them by parentId and then selects the first item in each of those groups. This could be tweaked if you wanted to further refine the choice of which one to choose.

**Additional Note:**

As an exercise in producing the exact output of the question the following can be used for childItems:

```
var childItems = persons.Where(x=>x.parentId!=0)
    .GroupBy(x=>x.parentId)
    .Select(
        x=>x.OrderBy(y=>y.Id%3)
        .First()
);
```

This is clearly a slightly absurd way of choosing from options but does demonstrate how you might change which item is selected by adding a sort criteria of some kind.

Comment: I got the first part but couldn't get the second childitems.

Comment: @alice7: Cool. Was there any criteria for which of the children you wanted to see? I assume you saw the comment discussion on the question itself on the subject and Adam would never forgive me if I didn't check... :)

Comment: Actually there was no specific criteria for children, that is why I asked for any child from a group.

Answer (score 5):

To get one person from each grouping of parentId just group on that value and then select the first from each group.  You can then concat that with the people with a parent id of 0.

```
var query = people.Where(p => p.parentId == 0)
    .Concat(people.Where(p => p.parentId != 0)
        .GroupBy(p => p.parentId)
        .Select(group => group.First()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a list of AllPersons:

```
var parentsAdded = new HashSet<int>();

foreach(var person in AllPersons)
{
    if(person.parentId == 0 || parentsAdded.Add(person.parentId))
    {
       persons.Add(person);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can still use loops.  Who knew?

Comment: He only wants one of each group of siblings, not all of them.

Comment: @Servy: this looks like it will do that (the second part of the if checks if anything in the target enumberable already has that parentID).

Comment: @Servy This will make a list with all 0 parent siblings and only one of each unit `parentId`.

Comment: My understanding is he wants all people with parentID == 0, and 1 person for each parentID.  So, if my "persons" list doesn't have a person with this parent yet, add it now.  I think that's what he wants.

Comment: @Chris & adam, for some reason Bill decided to name his result collection what the OP used as his source collection, this making it appear that he's searching the source for any parent, not the results selected thus far.  That's...not a good idea.  That, and it's needlessly doing a linear search in a loop, but yes, it is in fact correct.

Comment: @Servy: Yeah, you're right that there was some needless confusion related to naming and that the method isn't particularly efficient...

Comment: @All, agreed on it not being as efficient as some of the other choices.  But it does score points for readability.  Not the best answer, but a good answer for more novice developer.  And I was just following the naming convention of the OP.

Comment: @BillGregg A simple tweak to use a `HashSet<int>` to record previously processes parent IDs would improve the efficiency.

Comment: @BillGregg Actually it loses a lot of points for readability, not gaining them.  As stated, your naming of variables makes it appear to be doing the wrong thing.  Readable, by definition, means that when read it's easy to see that it's correct, not easily mistaken for incorrect code.

Comment: @Adam,Servy:  Point taken, edit made.  Participating in SO makes my code better, even when I'm not the OP.  Thanks!

Comment: @BillGregg You still have a problem that your result collection's name is what the OP uses as the name of his source collection.  That you say you're using a different source collection in English outside of your code doesn't make it poor from a readability point.  Next, you don't need to use `Contains` before adding, `Add` returns a boolean indicating if it already existed.

Comment: @Servy:  Thanks for the hint on HashSet.  Change made.  I disagree on your interpretation of the OPs naming convention.  I believe that persons IS the target collection.  See how he is adding his results to it?  You are interpreting it to be the source.  We might have to agree to disagree there.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be the one using two separate queries for `parentId == 0` and *first from group* merged using `Concat` method.

```
var results = people.Where(x => x.parentId == 0)
                    .Concat(persons.Where(x => x.parentId != 0)
                                   .GroupBy(x => x.parentId)
                                   .Select(x => x.First()))
```

However, it would require two passes over the collection. I would suggest writing your own Extension method for that:

```
public static class Enumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<Person> GetFirsts(this IEnumerable<Person> source)
    {
        var set = new HashSet<int>();

        foreach (var person in source)
        {
            if (person.parentId == 0 || set.Add(person.parentId))
                yield return person;
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it like that:

```
var results = people.GetFirsts();
```

**EDIT**

Or generic version of `GetFirsts`:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> GetFirsts<TSource, TKey> (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                                             Func<TSource, TKey> selector,
                                                             TKey zeroValue)
{
    var set = new HashSet<TKey>();

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (selector(item).Equals(zeroValue) || set.Add(selector(item)))
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: For the record iterating a list twice isn't really a problem.  If it was an `IQueryable` then yes, it would be, but it's not.

Comment: Yes, in the sample data there is no problem, but I'm pretty sure there is another source in real scenario and that's why it could be better to iterate only once.

Comment: The more conventional name for the generic version would be `DistinctBy` rather than `GetFirsts`.  See the [MoreLINQ version of that method](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs).

Comment: But it is not `DistinctBy`, because of `zeroValue` constraint.

Comment: Correct, it's a slightly modification of it, but that modification isn't indicated in the name `GetFirsts` either.